# golang change proxy after a web request

Tags: go, proxy, client

I was able to make a get request with the net/http package using a specific proxy with the code below:

```
proxyURL, err := url.Parse("http://111.222.333.444:80")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Bad proxy URL", err)
        return
    }

client := &http.Client{Transport: &http.Transport{Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyURL)}}
req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://www.google.com", nil)
res, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error")
    }
else {
    defer res.Body.Close()
    respBody, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body) //read the response
    fmt.Println(string(respBody))
    }
```

Reading the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ProxyURL) is written that

> ProxyURL returns a proxy function (for use in a Transport) that always returns the same URL.

But how should I make another get request after that one, in the same thread with a different proxy? am I supposed to create another Transport object with a different proxy setting? but I find this way to be very slow. What I'm looking for is to reuse the Transport and Client objects and changing only the proxy url.

What's the best way to do it?

Comment: I would create multiple http clients with different proxy settings and change those clients when you are firing the requests. 

The other way is to implement your own [http.RoundTripper](https://golang.org/src/net/http/client.go?h=RoundTripper#L115) but the implementation is not that simple. You might utilize default http RoundTripper for that implementation though.

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that creating a 2nd `http.Transport` would be very slow? It seems to me that this is the way to go

Comment: I feel uncomfortable to construct an object instead of changing only one of it's parameters, it is also becouse i need to perform some  thousand  of proxy change, so if there is a another solution i'll prefer to look into it